# storing an array as a linked list in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, linked-list, nodes

I'm working in C and am having some trouble. I need to store an array of chars (string) across a linked list. In other words, convert a string to a linked list. Basically, one character per node. For example string, dog\0, rather then storing a null character in the last node it would just point to a null pointer to signify the end of the string…… d->o->g->NULL

An suggestions would be great, thank you

```
int main(){
    char *string;
    string = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    strcpy(string,"cheese");

    node *list = NULL;
    list = createNode(string[0]);

    int i;
    for(i=1;i<strlen(string);i++){
        // this is where I'm stuck, the first char 'c'is in,
        // I'm guessing i wanna loop through and
        // store each char in a new node ? 
    }

    return 0;
}

node *createNode(char data){
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: create a linked list data structure and insert each character one at a time into the linked list...

Comment: `having some trouble`? Well, what exactly is that?

Comment: Please show us some code so we can better help you.

Comment: I don't think I can really go through and insert each char one at a time. I am reading from an input file, and the strings may contain many chars

Comment: will post code in a minute

Comment: If the length is tripping you up, just pull in the text in batches of whatever size you're comfortable with.  Read line, convert to nodes, repeat until the end of the file.

Comment: posted a little code. didn't include file pointer… just a string is easier for me to understand the basics with first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    node *next;
    char data;
};

node *createNode(char data, node *parent) {
    node *ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(ptr==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(parent!=NULL) parent->next=ptr;
    ptr->data=data;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    char str[]="cheese";

    // Store the string to the list
    node *first=NULL, *cur=NULL;
    for(int i=0, len=strlen(str); i<len; i++) {
        cur=createNode(str[i],cur);
        if(first==NULL) first=cur;
    }

    // Now print it out
    cur=first;
    while(cur!=NULL) {
        printf("%c\n", cur->data);
        cur=cur->next;
    }

    _getwch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually started modifying my code to something similar. Atleast I was on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If C++ is OK then here is a working sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[]="cheese", chr;

    // Store the string in the list
    std::list<char> clist;
    for (int i=0, len=strlen(str); i<len; i++)
        clist.push_back(str[i]);
    clist.push_back('\0');

    // Display the list
    do {
        chr=clist.front();
        cout<<chr<<endl;
        clist.pop_front();
    } while(chr);

    _getwch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm clueless with C++, even more so then with C… I know they have a container class that makes working with linked lists much easier then compared to C